# Package Inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

I am writing my thesis using MiXTeX 2.9 and Winedt 10 as my editor. I use `biblatex` with Biber as backend. I have created a main file, "thesis", from which I load individual chapters using the `\input` command. No matter what I do, I get the error message above in the thread title. I have tried removing section after section (and deleting output files between each run), but the error message persists until I have virtually removed everything.

I have also tried many of the suggestions given in the other threads on this common topic, but to no avail... Below is an example, and after the document I have added why I presume to be the relevant parts of the .log file. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[12]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xyling}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{cgloss4e}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\title{XXX}
\author{YYY}
\date{ZZZ}


\begin{document}

\maketitle


\tableofcontents

\chapter{Theory}
\input{chapters/Theory}
\chapter{Latin}
\input{chapters/Latin}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Log-file:

```
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\utf8.def"
File: utf8.def 2015/06/27 v1.1n UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu"
File: t1enc.dfu 2015/06/27 v1.1n UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
   defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C0 (decimal 192)
   defining Unicode char U+00C1 (decimal 193)
   defining Unicode char U+00C2 (decimal 194)
   defining Unicode char U+00C3 (decimal 195)
   defining Unicode char U+00C4 (decimal 196)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00C7 (decimal 199)
   defining Unicode char U+00C8 (decimal 200)
   defining Unicode char U+00C9 (decimal 201)
   defining Unicode char U+00CA (decimal 202)
   defining Unicode char U+00CB (decimal 203)
   defining Unicode char U+00CC (decimal 204)
   defining Unicode char U+00CD (decimal 205)
   defining Unicode char U+00CE (decimal 206)
   defining Unicode char U+00CF (decimal 207)
   defining Unicode char U+00D0 (decimal 208)
   defining Unicode char U+00D1 (decimal 209)
   defining Unicode char U+00D2 (decimal 210)
   defining Unicode char U+00D3 (decimal 211)
   defining Unicode char U+00D4 (decimal 212)
   defining Unicode char U+00D5 (decimal 213)
   defining Unicode char U+00D6 (decimal 214)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00D9 (decimal 217)
   defining Unicode char U+00DA (decimal 218)
   defining Unicode char U+00DB (decimal 219)
   defining Unicode char U+00DC (decimal 220)
   defining Unicode char U+00DD (decimal 221)
   defining Unicode char U+00DE (decimal 222)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E0 (decimal 224)
   defining Unicode char U+00E1 (decimal 225)
   defining Unicode char U+00E2 (decimal 226)
   defining Unicode char U+00E3 (decimal 227)
   defining Unicode char U+00E4 (decimal 228)
   defining Unicode char U+00E5 (decimal 229)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00E7 (decimal 231)
   defining Unicode char U+00E8 (decimal 232)
   defining Unicode char U+00E9 (decimal 233)
   defining Unicode char U+00EA (decimal 234)
   defining Unicode char U+00EB (decimal 235)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F0 (decimal 240)
   defining Unicode char U+00F1 (decimal 241)
   defining Unicode char U+00F2 (decimal 242)
   defining Unicode char U+00F3 (decimal 243)
   defining Unicode char U+00F4 (decimal 244)
   defining Unicode char U+00F5 (decimal 245)
   defining Unicode char U+00F6 (decimal 246)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+00F9 (decimal 249)
   defining Unicode char U+00FA (decimal 250)
   defining Unicode char U+00FB (decimal 251)
   defining Unicode char U+00FC (decimal 252)
   defining Unicode char U+00FD (decimal 253)
   defining Unicode char U+00FE (decimal 254)
   defining Unicode char U+00FF (decimal 255)
   defining Unicode char U+0102 (decimal 258)
   defining Unicode char U+0103 (decimal 259)
   defining Unicode char U+0104 (decimal 260)
   defining Unicode char U+0105 (decimal 261)
   defining Unicode char U+0106 (decimal 262)
   defining Unicode char U+0107 (decimal 263)
   defining Unicode char U+010C (decimal 268)
   defining Unicode char U+010D (decimal 269)
   defining Unicode char U+010E (decimal 270)
   defining Unicode char U+010F (decimal 271)
   defining Unicode char U+0110 (decimal 272)
   defining Unicode char U+0111 (decimal 273)
   defining Unicode char U+0118 (decimal 280)
   defining Unicode char U+0119 (decimal 281)
   defining Unicode char U+011A (decimal 282)
   defining Unicode char U+011B (decimal 283)
   defining Unicode char U+011E (decimal 286)
   defining Unicode char U+011F (decimal 287)
   defining Unicode char U+0130 (decimal 304)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0132 (decimal 306)
   defining Unicode char U+0133 (decimal 307)
   defining Unicode char U+0139 (decimal 313)
   defining Unicode char U+013A (decimal 314)
   defining Unicode char U+013D (decimal 317)
   defining Unicode char U+013E (decimal 318)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0143 (decimal 323)
   defining Unicode char U+0144 (decimal 324)
   defining Unicode char U+0147 (decimal 327)
   defining Unicode char U+0148 (decimal 328)
   defining Unicode char U+014A (decimal 330)
   defining Unicode char U+014B (decimal 331)
   defining Unicode char U+0150 (decimal 336)
   defining Unicode char U+0151 (decimal 337)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+0154 (decimal 340)
   defining Unicode char U+0155 (decimal 341)
   defining Unicode char U+0158 (decimal 344)
   defining Unicode char U+0159 (decimal 345)
   defining Unicode char U+015A (decimal 346)
   defining Unicode char U+015B (decimal 347)
   defining Unicode char U+015E (decimal 350)
   defining Unicode char U+015F (decimal 351)
   defining Unicode char U+0160 (decimal 352)
   defining Unicode char U+0161 (decimal 353)
   defining Unicode char U+0162 (decimal 354)
   defining Unicode char U+0163 (decimal 355)
   defining Unicode char U+0164 (decimal 356)
   defining Unicode char U+0165 (decimal 357)
   defining Unicode char U+016E (decimal 366)
   defining Unicode char U+016F (decimal 367)
   defining Unicode char U+0170 (decimal 368)
   defining Unicode char U+0171 (decimal 369)
   defining Unicode char U+0178 (decimal 376)
   defining Unicode char U+0179 (decimal 377)
   defining Unicode char U+017A (decimal 378)
   defining Unicode char U+017B (decimal 379)
   defining Unicode char U+017C (decimal 380)
   defining Unicode char U+017D (decimal 381)
   defining Unicode char U+017E (decimal 382)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201A (decimal 8218)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
   defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)
   defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
   defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
   defining Unicode char U+2039 (decimal 8249)
   defining Unicode char U+203A (decimal 8250)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu"
File: ot1enc.dfu 2015/06/27 v1.1n UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00B8 (decimal 184)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu"
File: omsenc.dfu 2015/06/27 v1.1n UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
   defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
   defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
   defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
   defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
   defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
   defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
))
```

Comment: It is easy to solve such problems -- but only if one has the files. In your case the input files and the bib.

Comment: current latex gives an easier to read error message but even the older version you have shows the exact character that needs to be defined if you show the exact error message. cut and paste the error from the log into a code (`{}`) block in your question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I have read through the -log file and I honestly cannot detect the error message there. I will edit my original message and add all the information from the .log file that seems relevant. But it does not say "error" anywhere.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, ok, what should I do? These exact tex-files compile just fine on my work PC, but I have simpy sent them to myself on email, and they won't compile on my laptop... Mind you, if I erase ALL text from the input files, and remove the \addbibliography command from the main file, (and erase the output files), the error still persists...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If I would guess I would say typical case of "I show what I think is relevant". (And I would guess some invisible space character is making the trouble, one of them which have been added to a current t1enc.def)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, this is the exact error message as I receive it, there is nothing further, no character mentioned. And as far as I can see, there is no error message of the kind in the log...

Comment: all tex errors go to the log, and there should be a (perhaps invisible) character after the :, but as posted here there is just a space.

Comment: Strange, there is nothing of the kind in the log file. I even searched it for "error", and that yields one irrelevant find, otherwise nothing. Possibly the problem is related to me having copied and pasted in the input files, say from one input file to another. There might well be a blank or something, but how do I find it?

Comment: I am sorry, @DavidCarlisle, but I don't follow you. When I try to compile my file "thesis.tex", the preamble of which is given above, by the command LaTex (Shift+Ctrl+L), I get this error message. And there is in fact no trace of it in the corresponding log file...

Comment: Do you stop the compilation when you get the error?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, it stops itself, I cannot continue from that point. Such a strange thinge. I bet it will work just fine if I actually made new input files and wrote everything all over again. But that will take several days...

Comment: hit enter when it stops.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks, I didn't even know that was possible. When I force the compilation, the resulting pdf-file does not seem to contain any errors that I can see at least. I suppose this suggests that the character in question is a blank or something? Anyway, for want of a real solution, this is fine with me for now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is not a solution. But it should give you a complete log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, you are right, now the log-file is complete and contains the error. It looks exactly like the one I have already reported: "! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX." What could I do with this information?

Comment: It should give you a clue where in the document the problematic char is.

Comment: Ok, here is the error message from the log: Chapter 1.
(chapters/Latin.tex
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX.


l.1 
       \section{The historical evidence}
? 
[5

]
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 24.
 [6] [7]

Comment: I take it that the error is in chapter 1, and perhaps even in section "The historical evidence" (?), but the funny thing is that even if I delete all text whatsoever from the chapter, erase output files and recompile, the error message is still the same...